# How can I use a custom class with Tailwind CSS for dark mode

Tags: tailwind-css, darkmode

```css
.zz3d {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4acab355 25%, transparent 25%) -12px 0/
      24px 24px,
    linear-gradient(225deg, #4acab3 25%, transparent 25%) -12px 0/ 24px 24px,
    linear-gradient(315deg, #4acab355 25%, transparent 25%) 0px 0/ 24px 24px,
    linear-gradient(45deg, #4acab3 25%, #ffffff 25%) 0px 0/ 24px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div className="dark:zz3d w-screen gap-8 h-screen bg-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
```

Why is this code not working and how can I fix it?

I am expecting to switch the background from white to my custom background when using dark mode.

Comment: Are all other dark mode code working? (Just to see if it's properly set up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `dark:` modifier for your class if you include the class in the Tailwind `utilities` layer.

For example:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .zz3d {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4acab355 25%, transparent 25%) -12px 0/
      24px 24px,
      linear-gradient(225deg, #4acab3 25%, transparent 25%) -12px 0/ 24px 24px,
      linear-gradient(315deg, #4acab355 25%, transparent 25%) 0px 0/ 24px 24px,
      linear-gradient(45deg, #4acab3 25%, #ffffff 25%) 0px 0/ 24px 24px;
  }
}
```

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-modifiers-with-custom-css